# Is this proof of the divergence of a serie correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to determine if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \pi^\frac{n}{2}cos(n\pi)$$

converges or diverges. I was given too the following theorems:

$T_1: $ If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

$T_2: $ If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n_1} \neq \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n_2}$, where $a_{n_1}$ and $a_{n_2}$ are two subsequences of $a_n$, then $a_n$ diverges.

The proof is:

$i)$Let $a_n=\pi^\frac{n}{2}cos(n\pi)$. Let's take the subsequences of $a_n$:

$a_{2n}=(\pi,\pi^2,\pi^4,...)$

$a_{2n-1}=(-\sqrt{\pi},-\sqrt{\pi^3}, -\sqrt{\pi^5},...)$.

Because of $T_2$, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}=\infty \neq \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n-1}=-\infty$, $a_n$ diverges.

$ii$) Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ does not exist as a finite number, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$.

$iii)$ Because of $T_1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \pi^\frac{n}{2}cos(n\pi)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct. Either of the two theorems may be used to show that the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. Alternatively, you could note that $\sum_{k\ge1}x^k$ diverges for $|x|\ge1$. Since $\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^n$ and $|-\pi^{1/2}|\ge1$ we have that the  series diverges.